# Estimate duration of DynamoDB data export via Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline

My DynamoDB table has around 100 million (30GB) items and I provisioned it with 10k RCUs. I'm using a data pipeline job to export the data.

The DataPipeline  Read Throughput Ratio set to 0.9.

How do I calculate the time for the export to be completed (The pipeline is taking more than 4 hrs to complete the export)

How can I optimize this, so that export completes in less time.

How does the Read Throughput Ratio relate to DynamoDB export?

Comment: If you have point in time recovery activated, there is a much easier solution available now, see the [news blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234662/how-much-time-would-it-take-to-migrate-data-from-dynamodb-to-s3) addresses most of your questions in regard to estimating the time for the Data Pipeline job to complete.

There is now a much better solution to export data from DynamoDB to S3, which was [announced in November 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/). There is now a way to do that from DynamoDB directly without provisioning an EMR Cluster and tons of RCUs.

Check out the documentation for: [Exporting DynamoDB table data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataExport.html)

Comment: Thank you Maurice, When We use "Export to S3" Option on Dynamodb , there is no option for "Import to Dynamo from S3".. Hence, we chose Data pipeline for Dynamodb data Migration.

Comment: That's a requirement you may want to mention in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package know as dynoport https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynoport will help you seamlessly import and export data from dynamodb